# Need help in understanding following JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't understand how the expression of return of following code works.

```
function reverse3(array) {
    return array.map((element, idx, arr) => arr[(arr.length - 1) - idx]);
}
```

This function gives reverse of array parsed to the function. But I actually don't understand and didn't get idea after googling for hours about how that statement in **map()** function works. Please give me explanation about for what those three variables stands and what that => operator does. THANKS in advance!!

Comment: refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map to read about map method

Comment: Thanks @quentin links you provided about arrow function are really helpful. Thanks again.